# Generating a signed app bundle does anything

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio fails building a signed app bundle without any message.

I am trying to generate a signed app bundle from one project and the build process ends after selecting the build variant, release in this case.

Just after clicking on the finish button it closes the window and makes anything further. No warning or error messages shown.

That happens only with one project, all other projects have no issues generating the signed app bundle.

I have tried all possible solutions, cleaning the project, rebuilding the project, invalidating cache, syncronizing with gradle files, restarting android studio, reinstalling android studio, but no success.

What should I do to get it working?

EDIT

Link to a video demo of the issue

[enter link description here](https://faro.red/demo.mov)

Comment: In your app's build.gradle file, do you have the signingConfigs block added in the android block?  ```signingConfigs {
        test {
            storeFile file("test.keystore")
            storePassword "somePass"
            keyAlias "someAlias"
            keyPassword "somePass"
        }
        release {
            storeFile file("release.keystore")
            storePassword "Ry5WeVVIJQn3TVZClQdG"
            keyAlias "my_alias"
            keyPassword "Ry5WeVVIJQn3TVZClQdG"
        }
    }```

Comment: @Jarvis, no, I don´t have added anything like that in the android block

Comment: @Jarvis, I am working also with other projects and generating their signed bundles without any issue. Only this project has this issue trying to generate the signed app bundle

Comment: @Jarvis, I have included a link to a video demo from the issue.

Comment: Any update on this?  I think I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: @BenJasperson, not really. I had to reinstall Android Studio and now everything is working as expected.

Comment: I was able to generate the bundle by first deleting the .idea folder.   Hopefully, I won't have to keep doing that, but I guess it wouldn't be a huge deal.